# In which folder should my QA functional Maven/TestNG test cases go? And its impact on CI process?

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, testng, continuous-deployment

I am writing functional automation test cases using Maven/TestNG. Following the convention, I have put them in `src/test` folder. But I understand there is another perspective that they should go in `src/main`. The reason is - in this case, the test cases will packaged like an application. The `src/test` folder should be for dev unit tests. So my questions are:

1. What is the correct location for the test cases?
2. If the location is `src/test` (used currently), then does it impact the CI build and deployment and packaging of these test cases? The end result expected is that these end to end test cases should be deployed and executed.
3. If the location needs to be changed to `src/main`, what other changes in configuration or elsewhere need to be made?